# Setting up Lynx Browser on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, lynx

Can anyone provide a walk through of getting the Lynx browser up and running on Windows 7. I want to do some accessibility testing with this browser but I can't find any simple steps to getting it working.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm worked flawlessly for me under windows 7

Comment: This one is currently at version 2.8.3, which as the author states is 10+ years out of date. For the latest versions, see the link in Jonathan Hult's answer, or see the list of maintained [Windows Binaries on the official Lynx website](http://lynx.isc.org/release/).

Comment: Why isn't Lynx maintained if it's apparently so useful?

Comment: @SarahofGaia  It is not useful.  It is a text based browser which is of very little use.

Comment: Lynx is very useful to scrape sites where you need to log in etc.

Answer (score 8):

There is a Windows installer for the latest stable version 2.8.7 located [here](http://invisible-island.net/lynx/#installers).

Comment: And the latest version, too +1

Answer (score 0):

A more in depth instruction set in case you have issues.

http://www.jim.spath.com/lynx_win32/readme.txt